# Trigger event for nested Updatepanel not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have the following situation:

```
Updatepanel
   dynamically loaded Usercontrol
      Button
      UpdatePanel2
```

I am loading a Usercontrol with another Updatepanel inside of it. Now in this usercontrol, i have a button which is registered as an async postback trigger for the 2nd Updatepanel. However when I click the button, nothing happens. While debugging, it does not even step into the Click event of the Button which sits in the usercontrol of course. The Parent Updatepanel ist set to Updatemode conditional and ChildrenAsTriggers="false". The nested UpdatePanel2 is set to Updatemode=Conditional. 
I just want the Parent Updatepanel to do nothing and the button to fire its event so that I can load some data in the nested updatepanel. Can anyone offer some insight?
I am using ASP.NET 3.5.

Comment: If you just put your user control in the page markup (i.e. not dynamically loading it), does it work then?

Comment: If you don't want the parent update panel to do anything, why do you need it?

Comment: I need it because, I want to dynamically load the usercontrols without a postback.

Comment: I tried it without the parent update panel it still does not correctly update the "nested" updatepanel. Actually the button in the usercontrol registered for the updatepanel2 causes a full postback on the main page and does not fire its event in the user control. I guess there's the problem. The Updatepanel in the usercontrol somehow does not connect to the button although the trigger is registered.